# Book ordering comparison between spreadsheets for existing catalogue of a Library

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I have recently asked this question of google's spreadsheet page.

I a significant data comparison problem I would like to solve.  It relates to purchasing books for a Library.  We have a catalogue of over 11,000 books. When we order new books we need to compare our proposed purchases to the current stock. Currently we can manually compare them to our catalogue, very laboriously book by book.

We need to do 3 things to make our life easier -
1 easily clean out bad data/characters in the ISBN's - these are either spaces, - (hyphen's) or . (period mark or full stops).  A simple formula to run over all ISBN fields would be great.
2 I need to compare data between 1 spreadsheet with 11,000 books in it (current library stock), a second with  up to 1000 books in it (currently on order) and finally the third currently active one (about to be ordered) with 50 to 200 books listed in it.

All spreadsheets use the same column configuration as below

Library orders
Title   Author  Publisher   ISBN (long version) US$ UKgpd   HK$ Other$          P/O no. Date ordered
UNNATURAL SELECTION MARA HVISTENDAHL    Public Affairs Publishing; Reprint edition (May 1, 2012)    978610391511

Finally, the out put of these comparisons should quickly and easily identify on what lines we have matches. and what type of match it is, Author only, Author and Title, or Author, title and ISBN etc for all the possible combinations.  To make this easier assume spreadsheet 1 is an unalterable master table, with spreadsheet two similar. It is really only on Spreadsheet 3 we need to be clear if we are starting to reorder materials.

If it is possible to have these as different sheets in a workbook it would be ideal.  The only additional feature is that any scripts that run need to be able to cope with spreadsheet 1 increasing in size as new acquisitions arrive and are included. Both spreadsheets 2 and 3 will vary (increase and decrease) as the ordering process proceeds.

Finally the absolute ideal would be for this comparison process to be instant (live) and ongoing as data is included.

If anyone would like to take this on 3 Library staff will be eternally grateful.

regards
Nick

Answer (score 0):

This would be very much easier had you one sheet rather than three (simply add a column to each existing sheet to show whether in stock, on order or to be ordered – three individual letters would be sufficient, then append each of the smaller two files to the largest). Then for example you could apply Conditional Formatting to highlight duplicates one column at a time (Author, Title etc). Apart from the initial data cleansing  it would mean in the future switching ‘between sheets’ would merely involve changing a one-letter flag. Filtering would allow you and your colleagues to appear to have three separate sheets and if anyone asks for a particular Title the search would be one-time, not in triplicate.

Also, http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15011 may be of interest, also =SUBSTITUTE.And with data validation you would prevent entry of a `new` ISBN that already is in your list.